# How to use dynamic path for images in Wordpress 3.6.1

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Currently I am working on a Wordpress website.

I have multiple websites on my webserver so my Wordpress site is located at `http://localhost/wordpress/`

Now I want to have dynamic paths for my images.

As HTML for my logo I use

```
<img src="images/logo.png" />
```

And in my `.htaccess` I use

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ wp-content/uploads/$1 [L]
```

This is only working on my homepage. When I go to the contact page `http://localhost/wordpress/contact`

I need to change my logo HTML to `<img src="../images/logo.png" />` to have it working on the pages.

How can I point my htaccess record to the root so that I allways can use the path `images/(.*)`?

I think I forget the `RewriteCond` but I have tried some and nothing works, even some internal server errors appears.

How can I do this?

My complete `.htaccess` looks like

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ wp-content/uploads/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to use absolute URLs for images which would always start with `/`

```
 <img src="/images/logo.png" />
```

**And in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` use same rule i.e.**

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)$ /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working on my homepage nor my contact page.

Comment: Yes, now it works. But when I move the Wordpress website to the root domain or move it to a hosting service, I need to change all my sources of images. So this way, my links are not dynamic anymore. What I want is only using `/images/` part in my image paths. I'm ok by changing 1 row in my `.htaccess`. But now I am unable to move my website.

Comment: So you are concerned about changing WP install path to something other than `/wordpress` in future?

Comment: Check the edited answer. Now this rule should be placed in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`. This way you don't need to put `/wordpress` in all of your images.